# C# mono from windows to mac

Tags: macos, mono, porting

I wanted to know what i shouldn't do in code that will prevent my C# app from running on mac.

Answer (score 4):

In general you shouldn't use anything from the `Microsoft.*` namespaces,  no PInvoke (`DllImport` in C#) and UI might be problematic as well.

Further information on Mono compatibility is contained in the Mono Guide [**Porting Winforms Applications**](http://www.mono-project.com/Guide:%5FPorting%5FWinforms%5FApplications). Existing applications can be checked for compatibility using the [Migration Analyzer](http://mono-project.com/MoMA) tool.

UPDATE: PInvoke actually works in Mono, but if you want to have it working cross-platform you must provide a native shared library with the same interface for each platform (i.e. Win API most likely will *not* work).

Answer (score 4):

Mono's [Application Portability](http://mono-project.com/Guidelines:Application_Portability) guide is a good reference.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to divo's recommendations, I would recommend the [Mono Migration Analyzer (MoMA) tool](http://mono-project.com/MoMA): "The Mono Migration Analyzer (MoMA) tool helps you identify issues you may have when porting your .Net application to Mono"

Also, I would keep an eye on [Miguel de Icaza's blog](http://tirania.org/blog/), and the [Mono Project website](http://mono-project.com/).

In his presentation for the Boston.NET Users Group this month, he showed a preview of a Visual Studio plugin that launches your app on Mono using a VM! This lets you test compatibility during the development process.

I believe their goal was to release it at TechEd 2009, so look for an update over the next month or so.

Answer (score 0):

You will, at the very least, want to try and avoid using Windows Forms, since that is just a paper-thin layer on top of the Windows native UI.

<strike>Mono emulates it somewhat with help from WINE, but I wouldn't trust that.</strike>
Mono did this a while ago but the effort was abandoned. See [WinForms on Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/WinForms) for more information. Thanks [jpobst](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16089/jpobst).

Try using GTK# or Qt# (although I'm not too sure the latter one actually exists) for cross platform support. You might also consider using Java with SWT or even Swing instead of C#, but that will probably not be an option you're willing to consider.

Using anything related to P/Invoke is probably also a bad idea, since that invokes native code which will probably not be portable (unless you write it yourself, then you can choose to make it portable).

Comment: How can i build GUI in MSVS for GTK or QT?

Comment: You can start by looking at this tutorial: http://mono-project.com/GtkSharpBeginnersGuide

Using Qt in .NET is a little more involved, but you can find a walkthrough here: http://doc.trolltech.com/4.2/activeqt-dotnet.html

Comment: Mono using WINE is incorrect.  Mono's Winforms implementation is completely managed, using System.Drawing to draw all the controls.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure if it is possible with mono, but WIN32 API calls will definitly not work ;)

Comment: What a useless answer.